# Which parts of the Visual Studio IDE are open source?

Tags: visual-studio, open-source, ide

Which parts of the Visual Studio IDE (if any) are open source? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the components in Visual Studio that I am aware of which have some level of source accessibility.

- MEF
- Iron Languages
- DLR
- F#
- CLR: subset of the CLR known as Rotor is open source
- BCL, WinForms an WPF: source is available under the [Source Reference License](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/referencesourcelicense.mspx)
- Plugin's: Many of the Visual Studio employee plugins available on the Visual Studio gallery have source accessibility.

Note: I intentionally used "some level of source accessibility" instead of "open source".  The term "open source" has a very specific meaning to certain portions of the developer population which does not align with the components I've listed here.  In particular they deam it to mean source which is contributable by anyone.  There is no part of Visual Studio today (that I'm aware of) which has that level of open source about it.

Comment: Reference Source license.  Also covers WPF and Winforms source code.  Link: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/referencesourcelicense.mspx

Answer (score 1):

None of it, so far as I know.

Comment: What about MEF ?? Visual Studio (at least 2010) uses MEF as its extensibility mechanism, and as far as I recall, MEF is available as open-source under a MS licence...

Comment: MEF is an OS technology from MS, like Iron python and others, but though it's used in VS its not really part of VS is it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, none of it, though I can see where the confusion came frome.

Microsoft did give "Visual Studio Industry Partners" [access to the Visual Studio source code](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Application-Development/Microsoft-to-Give-Partners-More-Access-to-Orcas-IDE-Code/).  This falls under their umbrella of "shared source".

But their umbrella of "shared source" is really, really wide.  Microsoft uses this term for a whole cornucopia of licenses that range from completely open-source to completely proprietary.

In this case, it doesn't look like the Visual Studio IDE is available under any of the open-source licenses.